# switch не срабатывает на 1 параметре

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

При указании числа больше 1 к единице времени добавляется буква `'s'` для отображения множественного числа. На первом параметре `label1` не срабатывает, а на втором параметре `label2` срабатывает и добавляет букву `'s'`. 
Как сделать, чтобы условие везде срабатывало?

```js
function timeAdder(value1,label1,value2,label2){
  switch(value1,label1,value2,label2){
    case value1: 
        typeof value1 === 'number' ? value1 : false;
        break;
    case label1: 
        label1 = (value1 > 1 && label1[label1.length - 1] !== 's') ? (label1  + 's') : label1;
        break;
    case value2: 
        typeof value2 === 'number' ? value2 : false;
        break;
    case label2: 
        label2 = (value2 > 1 && label2[label2.length - 1] !== 's') ? (label2  + 's') : label2;
        break;
    
  }
  return value1 + ', ' + label1 + ', ' + value2 + ', ' + label2;
}
      
console.log(timeAdder(12,'minute',5,'hour'))
```

Comment: `switch(value1,label1,value2,label2){` - а может прочитаешь, как вообще switch устроен? И заодно, что такое _оператор запятая_ - именно оператор, а не просто про запятую.

Comment: А разве так можно? `switch(value1,label1,value2,label2)`

Comment: Впрочем, `typeof value1 === 'number' ? value1 : false;` - это тоже фигня какая-то.

Comment: Спасибо, что помогли. Почитаю.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, синтаксически можно - оператор запятая. Но в данном случае совершенно бессмысленно.

Comment: Ну вот в том-то и вопрос, какбэ, уважаемые знатоки.

Comment: @Qwertiy именно тот случай, когда можно, но абсолютно не нужно.

Comment: Вопрос не в том, чтобы оптимизировать код, а в том, чтобы сделать его рабочим. Если бы его нужно было бы сделать лучше, то я бы и задавал вопрос об этом, а я задаю вопрос, как сделать этот код рабочим, потому что я не понимаю, почему не срабатывает условие на обоих параметрах.

Answer (score 0):

Не срабатывает, так как в switch может срабатывать только выводится только одно условие, последнее верное, что бы вывелось два их просто объединяют,  вот так.

```
  function timeAdder(value1,label1,value2,label2){
  switch(value1,label1,value2,label2){
    case value1: 
        typeof value1 === 'number' ? value1 : false;
        break;
    case label1:
    case label2:  
        label1 = (value1 > 1 && label1[label1.length - 1] !== 's') ? (label1  + 's') : label1;
 label2 = (value2 > 1 && label2[label2.length - 1] !== 's') ? (label2  + 's') : label2;
        break;
    case value2: 
        typeof value2 === 'number' ? value2 : false;
        break; 
  }
  return value1 + ', ' + label1 + ', ' + value2 + ', ' + label2;
}

console.log(timeAdder(12,'minute',5,'hour'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Не самый лучший, но рабочий вариант.

```js
function timeAdder(value1,label1,value2,label2){
    switch(value1){
        case value1: 
            value1 = typeof value1 !== 'number' ? false : value1;
            break;
    }
    switch(value2) {
        case value2: 
            value2 = typeof value2 !== 'number' ? false : value2;
            break;
    }
    switch(label1) {
        case label1: 
            label1 = (value1 > 1 && label1[label1.length - 1] !== 's') ? (label1  + 's') : label1;
            break;
    }
    switch(label2) {
        case label2: 
            label2 = (value2 > 1 && label2[label2.length - 1] !== 's') ? (label2  + 's') : label2;
    }
  return value1 + ', ' + label1 + ', ' + value2 + ', ' + label2;
}
      
console.log(timeAdder(1,'minute',17,'hour'));
```

Comment: в текущем виде все switch можно вообще убрать, если в значениях не может быть `NaN`.

Comment: Ну вот что-то все комментариев много оставили, как на философском форуме, а вменяемый рабочий вариант или совет - вообще по нулям. Поэтому сделал, как сделал. У меня тим-лида под боком нет, чтобы подсказал адекватный вариант.

Comment: Так тебе ж подсказали, что именно у тебя не работает. Плюс в предыдущем комментарии был конкретный совет.

Comment: Мне это не помогло.

Comment: что именно не помогло? подсказка убрать все `switch...case` из кода в твоем ответе?

Comment: Мне нужно решить задачу, используя switch!

Comment: В текущей задаче swtich Не нужен. Либо ты плохо описал свою задачу